# How email clients behave when met unsupported CSS?

Tags: html, css, email

In normal world, when browser doen't support some CSS property, it just ingnores this property, and styles are calculated without it, am I right? So the question is: does email clients behave the same way as the browsers, or there are some differences/caveats?

Comment: Sane clients such as Thunderbird certainly behave in this way. I'm pretty sure there are caveats with other clients though.

Comment: Emails are pretty archaic in a sense of you can code it with tables and inline styles easily so that it's compatible in all email clients. There are a few rules you'll need to set though like `border-collapse: collapse;` and so on to hide the borders on gmail (Just an example)

Comment: @Gezzasa I'm pretty interested in some properties like ```background-image``` and, as a part, ```linear-gradient```. These cases are supported by most of modern clients except Outlook and other native Windows clients (they have the most poor CSS support), so I'm wondering how they will behave with unsupported CSS, because I have no possibility to check it by myself :(

Comment: Ah okay, fair enough. Life of a developer I guess haha. Only thing I can suggest is to use Virtual Machines with windows set up. There are paid services that can test your emails for you and apps such as https://www.everlytic.co.za/ (Used to be pmailer) that you import your mailer and can test it on most email clients. Not sure about the costs

Comment: Cheapest service I found (Didn't look long so probably better options available) https://mailchimp.com/pricing/

Comment: @Gezzasa wow, thank you, I'll check it :)

Comment: Hope it works :)